# Bumblebee and AMD Radeon cards

Tags: intel-graphics, radeon, ati, bumblebee

Does Bumblebee (https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee) work with AMD Radeon HD/Intel cards or just with nVidia/Intel cards? Should I always run applications using optirun before the command name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The official AMD `fglrx` driver has some support for hybrid graphics itself; there's less need for Bumblebee and solutions like that.

Of course, this doesn't work on the AMD/Intel hybrid system *I* have, so I'm not sure quite how good the support is. ☺

Comment: It does? Which AMD driver version has this support? I've given up hope already. Although that was more than a year ago when I was still using 11.04/11.10 and I regretted so much why I bought a laptop with a stupid AMD hybrid graphics.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the very first stuff you read from the Site.

[...]nVidia Optimus support for Linux[...]

***Bumblebee aims to provide support for nVidia Optimus laptops for GNU/Linux
distributions***. Using Bumblebee, you can use your nVidia card for rendering
graphics which will be displayed using the Intel card.

So no, it's for Optimus enabled laptops Only.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Bumblebee supports NVIDIA hardware only, but the Bumblebee Project team is investigating options for AMD Switchable Graphics Technology which can be tracked in [issue 52 on Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/52).

As far as I know, the fglrx driver already supports hybrid graphics as was mentioned in http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-909802.html. The radeon driver does not have this option, but may be supported by Bumblebee in the future.

As for your second question, commands must be preceeded with `optirun` only if you want to run it with the discrete video card, e.g. `optirun firefox`. It will obviously not work until support for AMD hardware is implemented in Bumblebee.